# XmlDocument.Load() method fails to decode € (euro)

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, xml-deserialization

I have an XML document `file.xml` which is encoded in Iso-latin-15 (aka Iso-Latin-9)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-15"?>
<root xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com/demo">
  <f>€.txt</f>
</root>
```

From my favorite text editor, I can tell this file is correctly encoded in Iso-Latin-15 (it is not UTF-8).

My software is written in C# and wants to extract the element `f`.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("file.xml");
```

In real life, I have a XMLResolver to set credentials. But basically, my code is as simple as that. The loading goes smoothly, I don't have any exception raised.

Now, my problem when I extract the value:

```
//xnsm is the XmlNameSpace manager
XmlNode n = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//root/f", xnsm); 
if (n != null)
  String filename = n.InnerText;
```

The Visual Studio debugger displays filename = `□.txt`

It could only be a Visual Studio bug. Unfortunately `File.Exists(filename)` returns false, whereas the file actually exist.

What's wrong?

Comment: I have doubled-checked the encoding with Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you tried, If the error occures too , if you are using a Stream for which you set the encoding manually? I would be careful with statements like "It could only be a Visual Studio bug"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't just use the debugger or the console to display the string *as* a string.

Instead, dump the contents of the string, one character at a time. For example:

```
foreach (char c in filename)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1:x4}", c, (int) c);
}
```

That will show you the *real* contents of the string, in terms of Unicode code points, instead of being constrained by what the current font can display.

Use the [Unicode code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) to look up the characters specified.

Comment: Not really the answer, but that's definitely the good way for debugging this situation. Thanks. Now, I konw the problematic character is `:0080`. This is a control character in Unicode. Interesting enough, that's the Euro sympo in Windows-CP1252. I think string should be implemented in Unicode internally, this makes me think more and more that there is a bug in the XmlDocument implementation.

Comment: @rds: Okay, so you now know it definitely hasn't decoded it properly. Next stop: what's in the file, in terms of bytes? And does .NET understand iso-8859-15 in general?

Comment: +1 I suspect the file is actually encoded in `windows-1252` and not `ISO-8859-15` at all. Does the euro character display when viewed in an XML viewer (eg a web browser)? Windows and .NET do support ISO-8859-15, but it's very rarely used.

Comment: Conclusion: Yes the input file has 0x80.

Comment: @rds: Aha. Okay, that should be 0xA4 according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15

Answer (score 5):

If I remember correctly the `XmlDocument.Load(string)` method always assumes UTF-8, regardless of the XML encoding.

You would have to create a `StreamReader` with the correct encoding and use that as the parameter.

```
xmlDoc.Load(new StreamReader(
                     File.Open("file.xml"), 
                     Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-15")));
```

**EDIT:**

I just stumbled across [KB308061](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308061/en-us) from Microsoft. There's an interesting passage:

> Specify the encoding declaration in
>   the XML declaration section of the XML
>   document. For example, the following
>   declaration indicates that the
>   document is in UTF-16 Unicode encoding
>   format:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
> ```
>
> ***Note that this declaration only
>   specifies the encoding format of an
>   XML document and does not modify or
>   control the actual encoding format of
>   the data***.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However, I cannot assume the input file is Iso-8859-15.

Comment: I understand the `Load()` method pays attention to the xml header, as I thought. Their implementation of `XmlDocument` would have sucked, otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does your xml define its encoding correctly ? encoding="iso-8859-15" .. is that Iso-latin-15
2. Ideally, you should put your content inside a CDATA element .. so the xml would look like `<f><![CDATA[€.txt]]></f>`
3. Ideally, you should also escape all special characters with equivalent url-encoded (or http-encoded) values, because xml typically is for communicating through http.

I dont know the exact escape code for € .. but it would be something of this sort

```
<f><![CDATA[%3E.txt]]></f>
```

The above should make € be communicated correctly through the xml.

Comment: Ideally, you should put your code in code blocks, so that they are correctly displayed afterwards

Comment: CDATA sections do nothing to help encoding issues. In fact, since they contain only raw character data, they prevent you using character references like `&#x20AC;` which is what you seem to be going for in (3).

Comment: Yes (2) is not specifically fixing the problem but is with intention of protecting more special chars if they will be in the value.. 

In (3) I purposefully put url encoding format example %3E (not a &#x20AC;) which should be decoded after extracting the value through code from xml.